# Does "have never done...before” match “sit and watch”?

Tags: sentence-construction

> I have never done this in my life before, simply sit and watch clouds.

Comment: No, it doesn't "match". You need Past Tense, because what you're *actually* saying is equivalent to *I have never simply **sat and watched** clouds before.*

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Is this a correct sentence? "I have never done this in my life before, I have never sat and watched the clouds."

Comment: Well, that's ***two*** "correct" sentences, yes. But the actual example in your question kinda "collapses" those two sentences into one (by replacing the full stop with a comma, and "deleting" the "predictably repeated" words ***I have never***). Even if they're not *actually* present, those highlighted words are "assumed" to be there, so the tense of the verb clause that follows still has to match them.